# Passing variable between function and sub

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to pass a string from my main function to a sub.

I get

> compile error: wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"

The applicable parts of the code are below.

```vb
Function Update_Information()
    Dim Master_Workbook As String
    Master_Workbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    OpenFileDialog (Master_Workbook)
End Function

Sub OpenFileDialog(Master_Workbook)
    Dim Import_Workbook As String
    Import_Workbook = Application.GetOpenFilename _
      (Title:="Please choose a file to open", _
      FileFilter:="Excel Files *.csv* (*.csv*),")
    If Import_Workbook = "False" Then
        MsgBox "No file selected.", vbExclamation, "Sorry!"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=Import_Workbook
        ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Workbooks(Master_Workbook.Sheets(Workbooks(Master_Workbook).Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = "Import"
        Workbooks.Close Filename:=Import_Workbook
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

- Use a `Workbook` variable instead of a `String`.
- If `Update_Information` doesn't return anything, it should probably be a `Sub` instead of a `Function`.

```
Public Sub UpdateInformation()
    OpenFileDialog MasterWorkbook:=ActiveWorkbook
End Sub

Private Sub OpenFileDialog(ByVal MasterWorkbook As Workbook)
    ...
    ActiveSheet.Copy After:=MasterWorkbook.Sheets(MasterWorkbook.Sheets.Count) 
End Sub
```

Other issues to consider:

- `Workbooks.Open` returns a `Workbook` reference that you can (or should) assign to a variable:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Import_Workbook)
...
wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

- (Thanks to @GSerg for catching) The Main Issue: [`Workbooks.Close`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.close) is different than [`Workbook.Close`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.close). You're attempting to use the former (which has no arguments) like the latter. You want the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. Ended up with the following that works so far.

```
Sub Update_Information()

    Dim Master_Workbook As Workbook

    OpenFileDialog Master_Workbook:=ActiveWorkbook
End Sub

Sub OpenFileDialog(Master_Workbook)

    Dim Import_Workbook_Name As String
    Dim Import_Workbook As Workbook

    Import_Workbook_Name = Application.GetOpenFilename _
    (Title:="Please choose a file to open", _
    FileFilter:="Excel Files *.csv* (*.csv*),")

    If Import_Workbook_Name = "False" Then
        MsgBox "No file selected.", vbExclamation, "Sorry!"
        End
    Else
        Set Import_Workbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Import_Workbook_Name)
        ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Master_Workbook.Sheets(Master_Workbook.Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = "Import"
        Import_Workbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You could also write it:  
`Sub Update_Information()  
    OpenFileDialog ActiveWorkbook  
End Sub  `

Comment: Or you could use `ThisWorkbook` which is more precise...if it suits your use case.